# Similar consult SQL using QueryBuilder or Eloquent from Laravel 4/5

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'd to know how make this consult using jquerybuilder or Eloquent in laravel:

> $results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM `visitors` WHERE `dni` NOT IN (SELECT `dni_user` FROM `register_solicitudes`) "));

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query Builder

```
 $results = DB::table("visitors")
             ->whereNotIn("dni",function($q){
                $q->select("dni_user")->from('register_solicitudes');
             })->get();
```

Eloquent

```
$results = App\Visitor::whereNotIn("dni",function($q){
               $q->select("dni_user")->from('register_solicitudes');
           })->get();
```